# Merging fastq files with same barcode in two different folders to another folder

Tags: bash, shell

I had two run of same sample ran twice one nanopore platform. Now I would like to merge each run generated 96 barcoded files.

So my files in the folders are as such from barcode01 to barcode96

```
RUN1                       RUN2
barcode01_filt.fastq.gz             barcode01_filt.fastq.gz
```

Now i would like to merge each if them to one single file into another folder.The output Im looking for is merged barcode for `RUN1` and `RUN2` into another folder `RUN3` with the same name `barcode01_filt.fastq.gz`

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So Im breaking down the problem into small pieces.
First I have put both the run into a folder.

Now Im looking for the files in both the folder

```
find Cov1_run/ -name "*filt.fastq.gz"
```

The next step would be if there is a name match in both the folder then merge them.

the output of the above find command

```
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode05_filt.fastq.gz
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode68_filt.fastq.gz
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode34_filt.fastq.gz
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode82_filt.fastq.gz
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode61_filt.fastq.gz
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode69_filt.fastq.gz
Cov1_run/RUN2/barcode18_filt.fastq.gz

Cov1_run/RUN1/barcode05_filt.fastq.gz
    Cov1_run/RUN/barcode68_filt.fastq.gz
    Cov1_run/RUN1/barcode34_filt.fastq.gz
    Cov1_run/RUN1/barcode82_filt.fastq.gz
    Cov1_run/RUN1/barcode61_filt.fastq.gz
    Cov1_run/RUN1/barcode69_filt.fastq.gz
    Cov1_run/RUN1/barcode18_filt.fastq.gz
```

So now I have to match like if both the names are same then merge them into a same name but in a different folder

```
RUN1 barcode05_filt.fastq.gz and RUN2 barcode05_filt.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance of fastq files but **how** do you merge them? Concatenate start of second one to end of first one - is order important? Alternating lines? Alternate paragrahs? Alphabetically sorted lines?

Comment: okay let me give my output.."Concatenate" yes just cat is enough to merge them

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated my question and cat is enough to mege them

Comment: I find it easiest to change directory to either RUN1 or RUN2, then run `for f in *fastq ; do XYZ; done` then `f` is just a simple filename with no path. You can then easily check for its friend with `if [ -f "../RUN2/$f" ]`

Comment: but how do i concatenate both the files ? I mean which part of your suggestion I have to check first if both the file have same name and then do the 'cat' right?

Comment: @PesKchan Do0 you really suppose to concatenate .gz files? I'd rather ungzip both, con catenate and gzip the result.

Comment: yes i want p concatenate the .gz files as need gzip final file to address the space issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested and conceptual because too large for comment:

```
cd RUN1

for fa in *.fastq.gz ; do
    # Deduce name of friend 
    fb="../RUN2/$fa"
    if [ -f "$fb" ] ; then
       cat "$fa" "$fb" > "../RUN3/$fa"
    fi
done
```

Comment: and it worked flawlessly u saved my 2 days of search sir thank you very much